# I need multi seek buttons flowplayer in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using flowplayer for playing videos and I use flowplayer seek APi and I have a multi videos in one page and I want seek buttons play for every video not only one video

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>video</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="flowplayer">
    <video>
      <source type="video/mp4" src=""/>
    </video>
    <div class="buttons"> <a href="#" class="forward">forward</a> <a href="#" class="rewind">rewind</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="flowplayer">
    <video>
      <source type="video/mp4" src=""/>
    </video>
    <div class="buttons"> <a href="#" class="forward">forward</a> <a href="#" class="rewind">rewind</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/lib/flowplayer.min.js"></script> 
<script>

flowplayer(function(api, root) {

$(".forward, .rewind").click(function () {
  if (api.playing) {
    var target = $(this).attr("class") == "forward" ? 3 : -3;
    api.seek(api.video.time + target);
  }  
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help please

Comment: Perhaps point us to the part of your code you think needs modification? Or explain what efforts you have made to modify the code?

Comment: The Script is provided from flowplayer forum admin, and as I said I want seek buttons work for the 2 videos in the page because when I click on seek buttons for the first video , the seek buttons effected in the second video , I know it's need jquery parent code or smoothing like that